# How to check type of namedtuple defined within a different scope

Tags: python, scope, namedtuple

If a `namedtuple` is defined within a function, is it possible to use `isinstance()` to check the type of the `namedtuple` outside of the function.

I'm surprised that I'm able to use `type()` to get the type, but the `isinstance()` function fails.

Example:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def parse_a(raw_string):
    Parsed_A = namedtuple("Parsed_A", "attr1,attr2")

    p = [x.strip() for x in raw_string.split(",")]
    return Parsed_A(attr1=p[0], attr2=p[1] if len(p) > 1 else None)

parsed_a = parse_a("thing1,thing2")
    
print(f'{type(parsed_a)=}')
print(f'{isinstance(parsed_a, Parsed_A)=}')
```

In the above, the `type()` function accurately returns the type, but the `isinstance()` function fails with a NameError, presumably due to the `namedtuple` being defined in a different scope.

Why is the `type()` function successful while the `isinstance()` fails?

Comment: `type` gets the information from within the object. `isinstance` needs the class that it needs to check against which is not available in its scope.

Comment: @rdas Ah, makes sense, thanks!  Is there a recommended way to validate the type if I'm feeding the namedtuple into a new function down the pipeline?  It seems natural to define the type within the initial function, but I s'pose I should define it outside the function if other functions need access to it for type checking?